# Generate custom socket id for socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

According to [socket.io documentation for generating custom id](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-instance/#serverengine) this should work:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('dotenv').config();

io.engine.generateId = (req) => {
  // generate a new custom id here
  var randomCode = '';
  for (let r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
    randomCode += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+'';
  }
  return randomCode
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected :D", socket.id);

  socket.on('storeClientInfo', (data) => {
    console.log(socket.id)
  });

  socket.on("private message", (anotherSocketId, msg) => {
    console.log(anotherSocketId, msg)
    socket.to(anotherSocketId).emit("private message", socket.id, msg);
  });
});

server.listen(4000);
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log('Server is running'));
```

but it doesn't work for me the console outputs:

```
a user connected :D wJ8d-SC2su9YYCdWAAAC
```

it should be 6 random numbers, the random number is just for testing I want to assign the id to the user id in the database later.

Answer (score 1):

use can assign custom params to socket

```
var users = []
io.use((socket, next) => {
  socket.customId = 123456789;
  users[socket.customId] = socket;
  next()
});
```

and you can use custom params in

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("sendPrivateMessage", params => {
    users[params.toUserId].emit("message", "you have a private message")
  })
});
```

Comment: But how to send a private message to this id?

Comment: i edited code for private message

Comment: Does it effect performance if storing all connected users inside array?, I really don't know how socket.io keeps the ids stored though

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: socket.io version 4.3.2

Comment: The best way to do this is just add the username to the socket like socket.username = “user” and store the active sockets in an array to lookup what user sent the message

Comment: Though this answer works, it's not exactly the answer to my question about socket.io custom id not working, one thing to mention that the users var needs to be an object not array `var users = {};`, also removing users by custom id from the users object may help in performance.